# how can I access to job_description field in the array?

Tags: python

I want to access job_description in the jobs array, but once some keywords are found in the field of job_description then overwrite with the given data "Found"

```
class Robot:

  def __init__(self):
    self.data_extracted = {}
    self.data_extracted['jobs'] = []

  def compare(self):
    words = "blue yellow"
    if "blue" in words:
      self.data_extracted["jobs"][0]["job_description"] = "FOUND" # IndexError: list index out of range
    else:
      pass
    self.data_extracted['jobs'].append({
      'job_title': 1,
      'company': 2,
      'city': 3,
      'date': 4,
      'job_description': 5,
      'url': 6
    })
    print(self.data_extracted)

robot = Robot()
robot.compare()
```

data sample

```
{
    "jobs": [
        {
            "job_title": "Security Manager",
            "company": "Robert Half Australia",
            "city": "Melbourne VIC",
            "date": "19 days ago",
            "job_description": "The Company\n\nOur client, an industry leading education provider, is looking for an IT Security Manager with a deep understanding of security infrastructure.\n\nThe Role\n\nThe aim of this Security Manager role is to manage a small team of Security Analysts, oversee security operations and establish strong security policies throughout the organization.\n\nWithin this role you will be responsible for, but not limited to, the following:\n\nDevelop security strategy, roadmap and documentation\nContribute to technical security architecture design\nOversee implementation of security solutions\nMonitor investigations into security incidents\nBudgeting and expenditure plan\nEnsure regular vulnerability assessments, penetration tests and secuiryt audits are completed.\n\nYour Profile\n\nTo be successful in this role you will be degree qualified and ideally have further security certifications (CCSP or CISSP). More generally, you will have experience of the following:\n\nFamiliarity with intrusion detection and penetration software\nSecurity standards\nSecurity information and management software\nCoding practices related to security and review of coding standards\n\nFurthermore, experience in the some of the following would be highly desirable:\n\nPenetration testing\nDisaster Recovery\nMalware\nSecurity Architecture and Design\nSecurity Governance\nRouters and switches and configuration of network hardware\nConfiguration of firewalls\n\nApply Today\n\nIf you feel you have the relevant skills and experience and would like to be considered for the position please click on the Apply button today.\n\nJob Reference No: 06810-0010735869",
            "url": [
                "https://au.indeed.com/rc/clk?jk=da7f11e33ccb4f8c&fccid=bc2f0862932e35da&vjs=3"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I expect the output of `IndexError: list index out of range` to be `FOUND`

Comment: You initiate `jobs` to an empty list (`self.data_extracted['jobs'] = []`), and then try to access the first element which does not exist (`self.data_extracted["jobs"][0]...`). This is what is causing your error. It is difficult to recommend a solution without better sample data and expected output.

Comment: I added a minimal sample data JSON from which the original script is doing . I only want to overwrite that amount of data in `job_description` to make a narrow field , and make a bit quicker than rendering the whole text

Comment: Still not sure on your input and expected output, but it seems something like a list comprehension: `[job for job in jobs if 'job_description' in job]`

Comment: this `[job for job in jobs if 'job_description' in job]` . how would it apply to this `self.data_extracted["jobs"][0]["job_description"] = "FOUND"` ?

Comment: I'm still not clear what you are trying to do. Your class doesn't take any data to initialize it, and the function `compare` doesn't take any arguments.  Given your sample data for 'jobs', what will this entry look like if the condition is True (i.e. `if "blue" in words`)?

Comment: `if "blue" in words` is true then our `'job_description'` field will be `'job_description': "FOUND"`

Comment: `for job in jobs: if 'blue' in words: job['job_description'] = 'FOUND'`

Comment: do you mean `jobs` as `self.data_extracted['jobs']` ?

Comment: It is hard to tell. As you have presented it, `self.data_extracted['jobs']` is an empty list (that is why you are getting an error when you access the first item).  My guess is that what you have posted is a simplification of your actual problem.

Comment: how can I change a bit the code to fix the solution?